# Optimal two-stage warming up of a bottle of baby milk

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life

Here's a common two-stage method to warm up a bottle of baby milk to avoid uneven milk temperature:

1) Heat up a bowl of water in a microwave oven.

2) Put the bottle into the bowl of heated water to let the heat exchange between the hot water and the cold milk.

Each stage usually takes a few minutes, and one often wants to minimize the total time. Thus the question:

How to compute the optimal proportion of the time one heats the water to the time one uses the hot water to heat up the milk?

Comment: Put the milk in the microwave for different lengths of time and measure the temperature each time. Plot the result. That's your calibration curve. As long as the bottle is the same, the milk volume is the same, the placement in the microwave is the same and the milk starts with the same temperature, this should be good enough to drop the second step completely.